# Lightroom 4 - Geocoding photos using location-based keywords

Tags: lightroom-4, geotagging, keywords

I have tagged all my photos consistently with location-based keywords, e.g. Geography > France > Paris. Is there a way to automatically copy this information from my Geography keyword hierarchy to the City and Country metadata fields?

Lightroom 4 is able to *reverse geocode* the geographic metadata fields (City, Country, etc.) from GPS coordinates using Google Maps. Is there a way to *geocode* GPS coordinates based on City and Country fields, so that I could see my pictures on the map? I would expect all the pictures to be placed in the center of the city.

Comment: Sounds like you need a location aware map, not to generate artificial GPS coordinates. Picasa does this I notice and completely automatically. Pictures I've tagged with a location name were shown with a map with pin at the expected position.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting to know that some services are able to read location tags. I'm using Flickr though.

Answer (score 3):

### Manual Placement

If you have entered the Metadata, then you can use the Library Filter for Metadata > Location to select all photos with that data.

Then, *making sure they are selected*, click on the 'Map' tab.
Zoom into Paris (or just search), and *Ctrl-click* (Windows) or *Command-click* (Mac OS) the map location **OR** *right-click* or *Control-click* (Mac OS) the map location and choose **Add GPS Location To Selected Photos**.

Comment: That's a good point. I can select the locations I've visited, one by one, and drag to the map.